# Проверка симметричности строки

Tags: c++, строки

Нужно как то проверить симметричность строки относительно центра.. Вернее: здесь идет проверка строки.. если можно убрать один символ, что бы  строка была симметрична, то он выводит "YES" иначе "NO" Код есть, но есть проблема со вводом (разрабы задания нахимичили)..  У них вводится лишний символ, в первых 2 тестах.. Который мне очень сильно мешает.. Этот символ - "enter".. Можно ли как то убрать его из кода, или ограничить входные данные, что бы этого энтера не было? (тестов около 100, и на 3 тесте он выдет ошибку, елси я убираю последний символ, то есть делаю так: length = text.length()-1;)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string text;
    getline(cin, text);
    int length, res = 0;
    length = text.length();
   // cout << length << endl;
    int i = 0, y = length-1;
    while (i<=y){
       // cout << text[i] << " " << text[y] << endl;
        if (text[i] != text[y] && res <2){
            res++;
        } if (res > 1) break;
        i++;
        y--;
        //cout << i << " " << y << endl;
    }
    if (res == 1){
        cout << "YES";
    } else  cout << "NO";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А на кой вторую проверять, если она перевёрнутая первая? Я подозреваю, что набор символов ней такой же.

Comment: imho такую функцию придется писать самому. Но, если строка перевернута правильно, то различных символов быть не может. Вам надо проверить правильно ли перевернута строка?

Comment: Нет, задача состоит в том, симметрична ли она относительно своего центра..

Comment: Я правильно понял, что на самом деле у вас есть одна строка и требуется проверка, симметрична ли она?

Comment: Да.. Все верно.. Можно вторую вообще исключить..

Comment: Тогда идите по строке с ее концов к центру и сравнивайте символы. `for (size_t i = 0, j = str_len - 1; i < j; i++, j--) if (str[i] != str[j]) return false; return true;`

Comment: Спасибо.. А еще вопрос.. У меня какой то компилятор злой ( с другим работать не могу, к большому сожалению).. Он enter считает за отдельный символ, можно ли этого как то избежать?

Comment: Он просто записывает строку в таком виде, и значения выдаются не верные: 'abca (здесь энтер)
'
NO...

Comment: Вы [минимальный компилируемый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) своего кода вместе с вводом строки в тексте вопроса приведите, тогда можно конкретно говорить.

Comment: Для всех компиляторов  enter считает за отдельный символ, потому что он и есть отдельный символ.  Вопрос в том, читается ли до этого символа или читается вместе с ним

Comment: читается вместе с ним..

Comment: Нет там никакого лишнего ENTER. Просто замените `res == 1` на `res < 2`. Если строка точный палиндром (симметричная в вашей терминологии), то res = 0. А вот отличие от палиндрома на 1 символ (если он может быть произвольным) этот алгоритм (imho) правильно не распознает.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю отличие ("порча палиндрома") может быть: 1) замена символа (именно этот вариант вы рассматриваете); 2) вставка; 3) удаление.

Comment: Я рассматриваю УДАЛЕНИЕ символа из строки.. ТО есть, если можно удалить 1 символ с строки, то тогда выводи да, иначе нет (иначе, это все остальные случаи...)

Answer (score 1):

```
string text;
getline(cin, text); 
size_t m = text.length()/2;
string s1(text.rbegin(), text.rbegin() + m);
cout <<((text.substr(0, m) == s1) ? "yes" : "no");
```

Весь ваш код...

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но он определяет "полином", а не "может ли строка стать полиномом"